# Cronjob not using aws_config_file

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, cron, configuration-files, amazon-elb

I am trying to use the `aws elb describe-instance-health --load-balancer-name` command and when I run the bash script that is using it from my terminal it works perfectly and return what I except; however, when the script runs from terminal it can do everything perfectly except that command.

I have identified the problem of the cronjob not knowing about the aws_config_file, though I can't seem to get it to realize where it is/use it. I tried putting this line in the bash script `export AWS_CONFIG_FILE=/home/ubuntu/.aws/config`

Any help of how to get the cronjob to realize where this file is/use it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone having this issue, the problem was the PATH. aws is located in `/usr/local/bin` so in the bash script we added `export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH` to the top of the bash script and it now works